# how to set html value of a button attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple problem. I have a button :

`<button id='myid' data-test='some test'>`

I want to chante the value of attribute `data-test`.

I am using the following jQuery code :

```
$("#myid").attr("data-test","&lt;script src='<?php echo $linkjs; ?>' &gt;");
```

this sets the value of `data-test` but I want to save this as html value. How can I set it as HTML value ?

Comment: You want the innerHtml of the button set to the value of `data-test`?

Comment: @kevin Bowersox exactly

Comment: so, basically you don't want value of data-test attribute to be escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#myid").html($("#myid").data("test"));
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DcsNW/

Comment: value is set to some test only not the test

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $button = $('#myid');
$button.data("test", $button.html())
```

This will set the `data-test` attribute to html of the button.

Comment: I dont want to change the inner html of button. I want to set the value of `data-test` attribute

Comment: @lord_linus This is contrary to the comment you posted above.  Could you provide more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can access the data-* attributes doing this : `$("#elem").data('text')` and set the value doing this `$("#elem").data('test', 'value');`.

So you can do :

`$("#myid").html($("#myid").data('test'));`

Comment: what is this id elem ?

Comment: It is a generic example, in your case 'elem' is 'myid'